# Joomla doesn't show registration form if SEF is turn on

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have built a website for a client.  However, I am experiencing a very strange issue. If I turn on Joomla SEF URLs, it does not show Joomla user registration form.  If I turn it off, it shows the form.  Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you're probably not assigning the registration module properly. Try assigning the registration module to all pages and see if that helps.